# is it possible to push to more than 1 repository with netbeans 7.3 beta git?

Tags: php, git, netbeans, netbeans-7.3

I am a new `git` user, using the built in NetBeans support on Windows 7.

I have made some changes to my project files on a development computer, and committed them to a remote repo. I would now like to use `git` (NetBeans) to push my project to a bare repo that I have created on my live web server.

Is this possible using NetBeans commands or do I need to go to the command line.

Comment: Why would you have two duplicate repositories in the first place?

Comment: @ColeJohnson one for deployment and one to push to... read OPs question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about using it in Netbeans, but the [Netbeans git docs](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#remote) appear to suggest you have to choose a repository to push to.

Comment: you made me realize that if you go to git>push you have the option to set the remote location , and you can therefore toggle back and forth between different repositories. Thanks.